# Why messages don't show up?

Tags: spring, internationalization, embedded-tomcat-7

I have message property files in my Spring web application. The following is a related configuration:

```
    @Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {

    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);
    return messageSource;
}
```

The message in the property doesn't show up but the key with a language suffix. For example, a key, nav.welcome, in the property file is shown on a web page as ??nav.welcome_en?? I use Gradlew to run my application. And I see the messages.properties file on the root of the class path.

```
C:\Users\vic\workspace-sts\myapp\build\tmp\tomcatRunWar\work\Tomcat\localhost\_\WEB-INF\classes>
```

After turning up org.springframework.web log level, I see the following related log messages:

```
DEBUG: AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext:649 - Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@2a83e48a]
```

and

```
DEBUG: AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext:639 - Using MessageSource [org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource: basenames=[classpath:messages]]
```

What is missing here?

Comment: try by removing classpath:

Comment: @Rembo I try your suggestion without a luck. My old XML configuration also comes without "classpath" part as  <bean id="messageSource"
  class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
  p:basename="messages" />

Comment: where you kept messages.properties file? in src/main/resources folder?

Comment: @Rembo It is in the root of the class path in a deployment environment. In the development environment, it is in the  src/main/resources. I am wondering whether the problem is related with view resolver or not.

Comment: have you configured LocalResolverBean?

Comment: and show in jsp how you used..

Comment: @Rembo   No. There isn't a such bean in my project Java configuration. It isn't in my old XML configuration either.